# What does invocationMocker::with() actually do?

Tags: php, symfony, mocking, doctrine, phpunit

I am trying to mock a Doctrine repository and have the mocked repository return different results depending on what is fed into the findOneBy() method. I use the following code when setting up my tests:

```
    $this->vacancyRepositoryMock->method('findOneBy')->with(['id' => 5000])->willReturn(null);
    $this->vacancyRepositoryMock->method('findOneBy')->with(['id' => 50])->willReturn($myVacancy);
```

Unfortunately, this leads me to get the following output:

> 1) Tests\AppBundle\Service\VacancyServiceTest::testAddName Expectation
>   failed for method name is equal to  when invoked
>   zero or more times Parameter 0 for invocation
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findOneBy(Array (...), null) does not
>   match expected value. Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
>   --- Expected
>   +++ Actual @@ @@  Array (
>   -    'id' => 50
>   +    'id' => 5000  )

Removing either of the two lines above gets rid of the error. What am I doing wrong here? Am I completely misunderstanding what `with()` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withConsecutive` and `willReturnOnConsecutiveCall` to put multiple withs and returns into the same function. I'm not exactly sure what happens when you write it like you did.

Your code would look something like this:

```
$this->vacancyRepositoryMock->method('findOneBy')->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->withConsecutive([['id' => 5000]],[['id' => 50]]) //array in array is on purpose
    ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(null, $myVacancy);
```

As for your question on what the `with` function exactly does and why your way doesn't work... I'm not sure.

Comment: It's when the method is called *with* these arguments. So you can offer different return values by arguments w/o having to re-implement the function (e.g. in an anonymous function) and still have a functional mock.